# css margin operation with floated element

Tags: html, css

In the following trivial html code:

```
<body>
   <div style="float:left">text 1</div>
   <div style="margin-left:10px">text 2</div>
</body>
```

why does this not separate "text 1" from "text 2"?  I.e. this ends up producing "text 1text 2".  Apparently the margin is taken against the body, not the first div. So, if I put do "margin-left:100px", then they show separation, because text1 is less than 100px wide.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First try the following as you will see that 100px is not enough, because you just float the first div but the second div will append right next to the first one.

```
<div style="float:left">text 1 text 1 text 1 text 1 text 1 text 1 text 1</div>
<div style="margin-left:100px">text 2</div>
```

You have to float the second div, too.

```
<div style="float:left">text 1</div>
<div style="float:left;margin-left:10px">text 2</div>
```

Comment: Yes, this works, thanks.  So if you don't put float on both, the second div is in the normal flow, and its margins are relative to the body?

Comment: Yes, you have to float both divs if you want to align them side by side.

Comment: I guess that's what's confusing: just putting float on the first div, aligns both side by side. While it does that, it's obvious margins don't work as expected until one makes them both floating. :-(  Thanks for your help.